# Add-ins not loading when opening excel file programmatically

Tags: excel, vba, add-in, excel-addins

I've seen some similar problems described by others before but no real solution. And I'm sure there is one.

I have a .XLA-add in configured to be loaded when I open up Excel. It works fine when I open documents or Excel it self. However, when my BI-system programmatically creates and opens an Excel-file the add-in does not get loaded. The BI-system opens Excel in a new instance so it does not help to have opened Excel on beforehand (and thereby the .XLA-add in)

If i Check Options-Add Ins it looks like the add-in is loaded but it is not!

What I've tried (and that does work) is to insert [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/806720/11683) into the created excel-file and "reload" the add-ins, but I want to find an automated solution!

```vb
Function ReloadXLAddins(TheXLApp As Excel.Application) As Boolean
    Dim CurrAddin As Excel.AddIn

    For Each CurrAddin In TheXLApp.AddIns
        If CurrAddin.Installed Then
            CurrAddin.Installed = False
            CurrAddin.Installed = True
        End If
    Next CurrAddin
End Function
```

Is there any way to load my Add ins automatically when instancing excel programmatically?

Any tips, solutions or workarounds are highly appreciated!

Best regards.

Comment: But what prevents you from running this function automatically on the Excel instance you've automatically started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be possible in VBA. I have come across this problem before, and used the implementation found here: [Excel interop loading XLLs and DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567512/excel-interop-loading-xlls-and-dlls)

However, that solution is for C#. The steps required may not be possible when coming from inside of an Excel VBA script. Perhaps there are some VBA implementations you can look at, but wanted to give you some sort of starting place because I know that is a frustrating place to be.

Comment: Thanks! Will check it, unfortunately my C# knowledge is very limited and my access at work is also limited (installing programs etc)