# task schedule excel vba with bloomberg

Tags: vba, excel, bloomberg

I am looking to use windows task scheduler to launch excel and run a vba macro to output prices from Bloomberg.  Any suggestions on how to do this? I have a method to launch excel but it doesn't seem to be loading the Bloomberg API.

Comment: When you open Excel via automation, add-ins are not loaded automatically - you have to load them using code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114702/add-ins-not-loading-when-opening-excel-file-programmatically

Comment: It would probably be easier to implement this in C# or VB.Net and using Bloomberg's API v3.