Problems when calling macro from Python: Cannot run the macro SAPLogon
I have an excel file that runs a macro. The macro runs with no problem when I run it from the Excel file. However, I want to open it and run the macro automatically each day. The PY script below manages to make sure SAP Analysis addin actived and open my desired excel file and start the macro:
import xlwings as xw

# Path to your Excel file
excel_file_path = 'Excel.xlsm'

# Create an instance of the Excel application
app = xw.App(visible=False)  # Change to visible=True to debug

# Access the COMAddIns collection from the Excel API
com_addins = app.api.COMAddIns

# Specify the ProgID of the COM Add-In
addin_prog_id = "SapExcelAddIn"

# Enable the specified COM Add-In
for addin in com_addins:
    if addin.ProgID == addin_prog_id:
        if not addin.Connect:
            addin.Connect = True

# Open the workbook
wb = app.books.open(excel_file_path)

# Run the macro
wb.api.Application.Run('RefreshData')

# Optionally, save and close the workbook
wb.save()
wb.close()

# Quit Excel application
app.quit()

Here is the macro RefreshData. Just simple connect to SAP Analysis, set var and refresh data
' Call SAP Logon
Application.Run "SAPLogon", "DS_1", "810", "user", "password", "EN"

' Set refresh behavior to off
Application.Run "SAPSetRefreshBehaviour", "Off"

' Set the variable
Application.Run "SAPExecuteCommand", "PauseVariableSubmit", "On"
Application.Run "SAPSetVariable", "0I_DAYIN", dateRange, "INPUT_STRING", "DS_1"
Application.Run "SAPExecuteCommand", "PauseVariableSubmit", "Off"

' Restore refresh behavior to on
Application.Run "SAPSetRefreshBehaviour", "On"

' Refresh all SAP Analysis data sources in the active workbook
Application.Run "SAPExecuteCommand", "RefreshData"

' Save workbook
ThisWorkbook.Save

But when run python scripts. The following error message appears

// Update
I think i found the root casue
I tried debug using app = xw.App(visible=True)
When running Python code, the workbook opens, but the Analysis tab does not load

Normally, it shows as below

I also found a post about this issue on the SAP forum, but there is no solution
enter link description here

Are you sure the SapExcelAddin is actually connected successfully when you run it via Python. There's no check after the for addin in com_addins: . . .  to ensure that the addin was actually found and successfully connected.

When starting an Excel instance via automation, add-ins typically don't load, so you need to make sure you load any add-ins you need.  See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/25114702/478884

This problem can relate to the user under which the python app is run. For that user the workbook should be in trusted location.
Log in the system under the user, run Excel and setup trusted locations.
