# I cannot use the formula from external addins(ex. bloomberg) when i open excel with (C#)

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, ribbon, excel-addins

I have to use the data from third-party DB.

and they provide us excel format with addins, when i open the excel, then i can see the data after few seconds( just like bloomberg).

[NORMAL_OPEN_Without_C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXIqK.jpg)

[But_like_this_TT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwAZr.jpg)

and now i want to use this data automatically but they don't have api provide. 
so i try to open the excel with C# programming ,and save&quit the file after few minutes later.

but i cannot see the ribbon menu when i open the file with C# program, the result of the formula also does not work .

**a.cs**

```
Application app = new Application();
app.Visible = true;


Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(Filename: @"C:\nn\a.xlsx");

Console.ReadLine();

wb.Save();
wb.Close();
app.Quit();
```

i want to know the way to have the result of formula from external-addins.

if there is another way to have the result plz. let me know TT

thanks.

Comment: When you start Excel via automation, add-ins are not loaded automatically as when you run the program manually: you need to load the one(s) you want. 
 See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089016/starting-excel-application-with-addins-from-c-sharp-application

Comment: thanks for your comment, i will try it immediately. i will  write the result after try.