# Open Excel with addins by default

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

I am trying to open an Excel with C# using:

```cs
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
ExcelApplication = new Excel.Application { Visible = true };
```

The problem is that Excel will open without default add-ins.

And when I open my excel manually, I have all my default add-ins.

Do you know how can I open directly this addins when Excel is opening?
I am not supposed to open this add-ins like `Workbooks.Open( .... xll)` but directly at opening because my application is not supposed to manage add-ins from the code.

Comment: How about simply using [`Process.Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start)?

Comment: Can I disable excel alert with process.start? 

I know we can do it using ExcelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false; but I need to use new Excel.Application.

Comment: I don't think so. Take a look by yourself for available [Excel command line switches](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#Category=Excel).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load a specific add-in you can follow the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089016/starting-excel-application-with-addins-from-c-sharp-application).
To load Excel as normal using `Process.Start` as Uwe suggested, try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567512/excel-interop-loading-xlls-and-dlls) - this gives you a COM object which you can call `DisplayAlerts` on.