# F# Excel Interop: Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") does not work

Tags: f#, excel-interop, f#-scripting

I am trying to use F# to automate some Excel tasks. I actually got two issues:
1. If I open a workbook using an Excel.Application instance, I would miss all the add-ins that would have been automatically loaded if I had just opened the workbook in Excel. So I try to open the workbook in Excel first, with all add-ins loaded, and then hand the instance to F#. Then I got the second issue:
2. The Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") actually open a new instance, instead of getting the existing instance. The code is below:

```
#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
#r "office"

open Microsoft.Office.Interop
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

let app = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
let app1 = app :?> Excel.Application

let wb = app1.ActiveWorkbook

let visible = app1.Visible

let n = app1.Workbooks.Count
```

and the output is:

> val app : obj
>
> val app1 : Excel.Application
>
> val wb : Excel.Workbook = null
>
> val visible : bool = false
>
> val n : int = 0

But I am very sure I have an Excel instance running and it is visible. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [Excel interop loading XLLs and DLLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567512/excel-interop-loading-xlls-and-dlls) I do not have Excel so I can't test it for F#.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Thank you very much for pointing to that post! It seems to be able to solve my problem, but needs some time to digest. I actually do not mind to do some manual operation so I'll prefer my second approach if it could work. It just looks unreasonable why it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have double checked my code and this is the way to use Excel from F# script (use Excel-DNA for other cases). However, very often (especially when using add-ins) Excel does not close properly and some semi-dead Excel processes hang in the task manager until they are manually killed. Probably you are getting a wrong process, not the one where you open your workbook.

Comment: Thank you very much! When only one Excel process is running the code does work! This is good enough for me now.